# Recovery the partition and data

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, data-recovery, time-machine, partition-recovery

I would like to know how I could recover information from a disk or failing to make the disk appear for windows to detect.

It happens that by mistake someone used it for the backup option in Mac OS, which is called time machine, and this option deleted all the information, but when I use some program to recover the information appears.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

The tool has the option for recovery partition, but any option afraid me, because I don't want that for error the disk format and lose any possibility to recover the data.

**The HDD has a format HFS+.**

[image: 4]

Comment: In any case - make a copy before any operation which alters problematic disk data (in your case I'd recommend full binary copy of device). The recovering operation may succeed, but it may fail with adding additional errors and decreasing the amount of data which may be recovered. But if this volume is not system or boot I'd recommend simply recover all files from it, then re-partition/format and copy files back.

Comment: Thanks for your help, well you recommend knoppix Linux for that?

Comment: For that - for what? I do not see where it can be applied in my comment... everything I have told is OS-independent.

Comment: Sorry, i just a question.

Comment: *everything I have told is OS-independent* And backward (OS cannot affect on anything I have told) is true too.